# what is the equivalent sytax for `Tensor.grad` in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, gradient

In the Pytorch, we can access the gradient of a variable  `x` by

```
z.grad
```

What is the same sytax in `Tensorflow 2`. My goad is to cut the gradient. Here is Pytorch code

```
if z.grad > 1000:
    z.grad = 10
```

Can tensorflow 2 apply the same functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in TF2, assume we define following variables and optimizer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)

x = tf.Variable([3.0, 4.0]) 
y = tf.Variable([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
var_list = [x, y]
```

Then we can get gradients by using `tf.GradientTape()`:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(x ** 2) + tf.reduce_sum(y) 

grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list)
```

Finally we could process the gradients by custom function:

```
def clip_grad(grad):
    if grad > 1000:
        grad = 10
    return grad

processed_grads = [tf.map_fn(clip_grad, g) for g in grads]

opt.apply_gradients(zip(processed_grads, var_list))
```

Note you may find the keras optimizers have `get_gradients` method, but it won't work with `eager execution` enabled which is default in TF2, if you want use that, then you may have to write code in TF1 fashion

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Assume I have many variable in the compute graph such as `x`, 'y', 'z'.   I only want to clip the gradient of `y`. Any idea to do that?   It seems that the `grads` is a list. Not sure how to obtain the graident of `y` in the `grads`. Thanks.

Comment: @jason Glad to help, from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient): `tape.gradient` return a list or nested structure of Tensors (or IndexedSlices, or None), one for each element in sources. Returned structure is the same as the structure of sources, so if your `var_list=[x, y, z]` then `grads[1]` is gradient of y